# How to use affiliate tracker with event booking plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla3.0

I want to use Affiliate tracker API with my event booking plugin.i want to tracke users against affiliate id. here is affiliate tracker api

```
$conversion_data = array(
    "name" => "Custom Order",
    "component" => "com_yourcomponent",
    "extended_name" => "The item name",
    "type" => 1,
    "value" => 100 ,
    "reference_id" => 234,
    "approved" => 1,
);

require_once(JPATH_SITE.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'components'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'com_affiliatetracker'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers.php');
AffiliateHelper::create_conversion($conversion_data, $user_id);
```